# jQuery Ajax passing e-mail to PHP script brokes js

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need to pass some variables to my `mail.php` script to use them for email composing, but as soon as I enter e-mail my script brokes down.

Seems like it converts the email automatically to URL and after that it will crash my JS or where am I wrong?

Below is code snippet (what causes problems):

```
      $(document).on('click', '.kinnitus', function(){
   var kood = '<?php echo $params->get('Kood');?>'; 
   var info = '<?php echo $params->get('info');?>'; 

   if(confirm("Saada kinnitus meilid?"))
   {
    $.ajax({
     url:"mail.php",
     method:"POST",
     data:{kood:kood, info:info, mail_from: 'mail@domain.com'},
     success:function(data)
     {
      $('#alert_message').html('<div class="alert alert-success">Kinnitus meilid saadetud</div>');
      $('#user_data').DataTable().destroy();
      fetch_data();
     }
    });
    setInterval(function(){
     $('#alert_message').html('');
    }, 5000);
   }
  });
```

and thats what happens after i add

> , mail_from: 'mail@domain.com'
>   without email it works like a charm.

[image]

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Can you post your entire ajax query including the variables?

Comment: Use single quote instead of double quote in json parameter like 'mail@domain.com'

Comment: Are you seeing errors?

Comment: @undrftd added full function with variables what work.

Comment: @rawathemant tryed also with single quotes, does not work also (updated code in question box)

Comment: @Dormilich no error, it just destroyes code.  (forces my js functions to plian html and prints it out)

Comment: @undrftd only error what i see is on the picture.

Comment: var mail_from = "mail@domain" + ".com"; works.. and mail@domain works... seems like it can handle @ symbol ... i am out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, @ symbol was cause of this wierd situation.. so..

i used litle "workaround".

```
   $mail_to_pass = rawurlencode($mail_from);
```

and decoded it on my mail.php.

so my mail was on passing mail%40domain.com